# Reverse all words, set "." and do the same for the next sentences

Tags: java

I´m trying to program for so long now and it won´t work. I need a program, which does following:

User Input: I´m looking for some food. I love food.
System Print: Food some for looking I´m. Food love I.

Reverse the words, UpperWord the first word, start with next sentence a keep the "." at it´s place.

```
package finaledition;

public class finaledition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder outputString= new StringBuilder();
        String satz;
        String wort;

        System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie einen String ein: ");
        String text = Input.readString();

        while (text.indexOf('.') > 0) {
            satz = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('.'));
            text = text.substring(text.indexOf('.') + 1);

            while (satz.lastIndexOf(' ') > 0) {
                wort = satz.substring(satz.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
                outputString.append(wort);
                satz = satz.substring(0, satz.lastIndexOf(' '));
            }
            System.out.print(outputString);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual result is:

```
foodsomeforlookingfoodsomeforlookingfoodlove
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to split your hole text into sentences:

```
String[] sentences = text.split(". ");
```

Then you need to make an arrays with the words:

```
String[] words = sentences[anIndex].split(" ");
```

Then, reverse the words array:

```
String[] reverseSentence = new String[words.length];
for(int a=0; a<words.length; a++){
    reverseSentence[a] = words[words.length - a -1];
}
```

And then add all the reversed sentences together and add a '.'.

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops is hard to understand and leads to errors and time wasting in attempts to dubug and understand that procedural code, instead of this you need to use `oop`, java is `oop` language. You need to create class `Sentence` that completely resolve your problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String userInput = "I´m looking for some food. I love food";
        final String expectedResult = "Food some for looking I´m. Food love I.";
        String[] sentences = userInput.split("\\. ");
        String reversedSentences = Stream.of(sentences)
                .map(sentenceString -> new Sentence(sentenceString))
                .map(sentence -> sentence.reverse())
                .map(sentence -> sentence.firstLetterToUpperCase())
                .map(sentence -> sentence.removeAllDots())
                .map(sentence -> sentence.dotInTheEnd())
                .map(sentence -> sentence.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        System.out.println(reversedSentences.equals(expectedResult)); //returns true
    }


}

final class Sentence {
    private final String sentence;

    Sentence(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    Sentence reverse() {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
        return new Sentence(String.join(" ", words));
    }

    Sentence firstLetterToUpperCase() {
        String firstLetter = sentence.substring(0, 1);
        String anotherPart = sentence.substring(1);
        return new Sentence(firstLetter.toUpperCase() + anotherPart);
    }

    Sentence dotInTheEnd() {
        return new Sentence(sentence + ".");
    }

    Sentence removeAllDots() {
        return new Sentence(sentence.replaceAll("//.", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sentence;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LalitVerma this is much simple than one simple loop. People programming to other people, not for computers. Code readability should be in the first place.